# VDM for Integration Tests

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I had used VDM in order to consumer external ODATA service. It is working well. Now I am trying to use the VDM for Integration Testing in order to test the created ODATA service using CAP Model.

I was using restTemplate.exchange() in the Integration Testing to test the ODATA service. It was working well. Now I had decided to go with SDK VDM approach.
The VDM files were generated successfully. But while trying to run the Integration Tests, it fails with an exception

com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.ShouldNotHappenException: java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method com.google.gson.JsonObject.get(java.lang.String) of a null object loaded from local variable 'xsuaaServiceCredentials'

I do pass the local JWT token & also VCAP_SERVICES set in the environment variable.

```
package com.sap.crun.landscape;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpConfigContext;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.testutil.MockUtil;

import com.sap.crun.landscape.vdm.odatalandscapeservice.namespaces.odatalandscapeservice.LandscapeObjects;
import com.sap.crun.landscape.vdm.odatalandscapeservice.namespaces.odatalandscapeservice.LandscapeObjectsCreateFluentHelper;
import com.sap.crun.landscape.vdm.odatalandscapeservice.namespaces.odatalandscapeservice.LandscapeObjectsFluentHelper;
import com.sap.crun.landscape.vdm.odatalandscapeservice.namespaces.odatalandscapeservice.Properties;
import com.sap.crun.landscape.vdm.odatalandscapeservice.services.DefaultOdataLandscapeserviceService;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestApplication.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:LmsTest.properties")
public class BusinessServiceIT {

    private static final Logger LOG = CloudLoggerFactory.getLogger(LisImporter.class);
    private static final MockUtil mockUtil = new MockUtil();
    private static final DefaultOdataLandscapeserviceService lmsService = new DefaultOdataLandscapeserviceService()
            .withServicePath("/odata/v2/LandscapeService");
    private ErpConfigContext erpConfCtx;
    private static final String jwToken = new JwtGenerator()
            .getTokenForAuthorizationHeader(LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".d", LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".r", LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".a");
    private static final LandscapeObjectsFluentHelper lsoCreateHelper = lmsService.getAllLandscapeObjects();

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        mockUtil.mockDefaults();
        mockUtil.mockAuditLog();

        lsoCreateHelper
        .withCustomHttpHeader("Authorization", new JwtGenerator().getTokenForAuthorizationHeader(
                LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".d", LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".a", LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".r"))
        .onRequestAndImplicitRequests();

    }

    @Before
    public void beforeEach() throws URISyntaxException {
        mockUtil.mockDestination("localhorst", new URI("http://localhost:" + randomServerPort));
        erpConfCtx = new ErpConfigContext("localhorst");
    }

    @Test
    public void parseVcapServices() {
        final SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyHolder = new SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        final String xsappname = propertyHolder.readVcapServices(SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.propertyXsAppname,
                "application");
        assertEquals(LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME, xsappname);
    }

    @Test
    public void createBusinessService() {


        Properties properties = new Properties();
        List<Properties> propertySet = new ArrayList<>();
        properties.setName("useCase");
        properties.setValue("XX");
        properties.setSource("XXX");
        propertySet.add(properties);

        LandscapeObjects landscapeObjects = new LandscapeObjects(null, null, null, null, null, "benufromit", "benufromit_test", BusinessService.name(), "123", "LMS", null, null, propertySet);
        LOG.info("benu-business1");

        final LandscapeObjectsCreateFluentHelper lsoCreateHelper = lmsService.createLandscapeObjects(landscapeObjects)
                .withCustomHttpHeader("Authorization", new JwtGenerator().getTokenForAuthorizationHeader(
                        LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".d", LocalSecurityConfig.XSAPPNAME + ".a")).onRequestAndImplicitRequests();

        try {
            lsoCreateHelper.execute(erpConfCtx); //It fails here
            LOG.info("benu-business3 {}", landscapeObjects.getId());
        } catch (ODataException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
 com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.ShouldNotHappenException: java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method com.google.gson.JsonObject.get(java.lang.String) of a null object loaded from local variable 'xsuaaServiceCredentials'
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.doFilter(RequestContextServletFilter.java:216) ~[servlet-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.16.RELEASE.jar:na]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:685) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [na:1.8.0_202] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method com.google.gson.JsonObject.get(java.lang.String) of a null object loaded from local variable 'xsuaaServiceCredentials'
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.AuthTokenDecoder.getVerificationPublicKey(AuthTokenDecoder.java:86) ~[security-scp-cf-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.AuthTokenDecoder.decode(AuthTokenDecoder.java:146) ~[security-scp-cf-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.AuthTokenDecoder.decode(AuthTokenDecoder.java:195) ~[security-scp-cf-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.AuthTokenRequestContextListener.getProperties(AuthTokenRequestContextListener.java:49) ~[security-scp-cf-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.AbstractRequestContextListener.requestContextInitialized(AbstractRequestContextListener.java:40) ~[servlet-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextCallable.notifyContextInitialized(RequestContextCallable.java:68) ~[servlet-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextCallable.call(RequestContextCallable.java:129) ~[servlet-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.doFilter(RequestContextServletFilter.java:209) ~[servlet-2.15.0.jar:na]
                   ... 76 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the stacktrace, in case there is a _Caused by_ reference further below?

Comment: It looks like your VCAP_SERVICES is malformed. You could try to adjust to look like one on Cloud Foundry until the `getXsuaaCredentials` returns something.

Comment: If you want to use `VCAP_SERVICES`, you have to add `clientsecret` as well (next to `clientid`). As part of your test, please check whether the environment variable could be correctly parsed, e.g. evaluate and browse `final JsonObject xsuaaServiceCredentials = ((ScpCfCloudPlatform) CloudPlatformAccessor.getCloudPlatform()).getXsuaaServiceCredentials();`. Also please confirm the following call will likely break your *test* runtime: `AuthToken xsuaaServiceToken = AuthTokenAccessor.getXsuaaServiceToken()`

Comment: The method xsuaaServiceCredentials = getCloudPlatform().getXsuaaServiceCredentials(decodedJWT) does not return anything. As I use mock, I could not debug this method. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated answer:***

After a call we concluded a method was not correctly mocked at test runtime.

Please add the following lines of code to your integration test with `@Before` annotation:

```java
final String publicKey = "...";
final Map<String,String> verificationkey = ImmutableMap.of("verificationkey", publicKey);
final JsonObject xsuaaServiceCredentials = new Gson().toJsonTree(verificationkey).getAsJsonObject();
Mockito.when(((ScpCfCloudPlatform) CloudPlatformAccessor.getCloudPlatform()).getXsuaaServiceCredentials(ArgumentMatchers.any(DecodedJWT.class))).thenReturn(xsuaaServiceCredentials);
```

This will make sure the tested application can correctly validate the provided auth token with a prepared public key.

I forwarded this scenario to our developer team, to consider a fix to this potential feature gap.

---

***Deprecated response:***

Some open points to progress the problem analysis:

1. Do you use Cloud SDK only for testing or also in the application backend?
2. Meant as a hint; I would avoid putting try-catch in test code.
3. It's recommended to instantiate a dedicated *ErpConfigContext* for each test case. Also please use the *RequestContextExecutor*:

   ```java
   import com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextExecutor;
   ```

   with

   ```java
   @Test
   public void createBusinessService() {
     new RequestContextExecutor().execute(() -> {
       ...
       lsoCreateHelper.execute(new ErpConfigContext("localhorst"));
       ...
     });
   }
   ```

Does this work or give you any other message?

Comment: 1. I use cloud SDK in the application backend to consume ODATA service from other cloud service
2. Yes. I will remove the try.. catch 
3. I had changed the code accordingly.  It still gives me the same error message

Comment: I had also updated my analysis on the VCAP_SERVICES

Comment: Hello Alexander, Do you see any problems in my approach? I am still struck